Codepipeline level variable is not getting resolved
How to get the resolved value of codepipeline level variable which defaults to #{SourceVariables.CommitId}?
I have setup a codepipeline having Bitbucket repo as Source and codebuild for deploy stage.
Use case: I want to access the commit id in codebuild. By default it should be the latest commit id of source bitbucket repo, but for rollback purpose, I should be able to manually pass an old/custom commit id if I want.
Implementation: The pipeline has a codepipeline level variable COMMIT_ID_VAR which defaults to #{SourceVariables.CommitId}.
AppPipeline:
  Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
  Properties:
    Name: 'test-pipeline'
    PipelineType: V2
    Variables:
      - Description: Change this variable to deploy a specific commit instead of latest commit.
        Name: 'COMMIT_ID_VAR'
        DefaultValue: '#{SourceVariables.CommitId}'

I have added COMMIT_ID_VAR as an environment variable in codebuild:
- Name: Deploy
  Actions:
    - Name: Deploy-Apps
      InputArtifacts:
        - Name: SourceOutput
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Build
        Owner: AWS
        Version: 1
        Provider: CodeBuild
      Configuration:
        ProjectName: CodeBuildProjectPreDeployName
        EnvironmentVariables: '[{"name":"COMMIT_ID","value":"#{variables.COMMIT_ID_VAR}","type":"PLAINTEXT"}]'
      RunOrder: 1

Issue: I am able to get the custom commit id in codebuild when I am manually entering the codepipeline level variable COMMIT_ID_VAR. But for default case, I am getting the string #{SourceVariables.CommitId} in codebuild instead of the resolved value i.e., the latest commit id.
https://i.sstatic.net/Q5iSBCnZ.png
How can I get the resolved value of pipeline level variable instead of "#{SourceVariables.CommitId}" for the default case?
